# Rewrite SQL query without nesting

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a table "births" given by:

```
create table births (
regno       int,
fname       char(12),
lname       char(12),
regdate date,
regplace    char(20),
gender  char(1),
f_fname char(12),
f_lname char(12),
m_fname char(12),
m_lname char(12),
primary key (regno),
foreign key (fname,lname) references persons,
foreign key (f_fname,f_lname) references persons,
foreign key (m_fname,m_lname) references persons
);
```

and I need to find all the people who have the same parents as a given fname, lname (Michael Fox in this case). I was able to do it with a big nested query, but how would I write the same query without nesting?

This is the query I have:

```
SELECT 
  b.fname, 
  b.lname 
FROM 
  births b 
WHERE 
  b.m_fname = (
    (
      SELECT 
        b.m_fname 
      FROM 
        births b 
      WHERE 
        b.fname = 'Michael' 
        AND b.lname = 'Fox'
    ) 
    AND b.m_lname = (
      SELECT 
        b.m_lname 
      FROM 
        births b 
      WHERE 
        b.fname = 'Michael' 
        AND b.lname = 'Fox'
    )
  ) 
  OR (
    b.f_fname = (
      SELECT 
        b.f_fname 
      FROM 
        births b 
      WHERE 
        b.fname = 'Michael' 
        AND b.lname = 'Fox'
    ) 
    AND b.f_lname = (
      SELECT 
        b.f_lname 
      FROM 
        births b 
      WHERE 
        b.fname = 'Michael' 
        AND b.lname = 'Fox'
    )
  );
```

Comment: By "same parents" do you mean both are the same or just one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can self-join the table:

```
SELECT b.fname,b.lname
FROM births b
INNER JOIN births b1
    ON b1.regno != b.regno
    AND (
        (b1.m_lname = b.m_lname AND b1.m_fname = b.m_fname)
        OR (b1.f_lname = b.f_lname AND b1.f_fname = b.f_fname)
    )
WHERE b1.fname = 'Michael' AND b1.lname = 'Fox'
```

This will return births records other than Michael Fox and who have at least one parent in common with him. If you need to match on both parents, just change the OR condition to AND.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`.  If one parent needs to be the same:

```
select b.*
from births b
where exists (select 1
              from births b2
              where b2.fname = 'Michael' and b2.lname = 'Fox' and
                    ((b2.f_lname = b.f_lname and b2.f_fname = b.f_fname) or
                     (b2.m_lname = b.m_lname and b2.m_fname = b.m_fname)
                    )
              );
```

If both:

```
select b.*
from births b
where exists (select 1
              from births b2
              where b2.fname = 'Michael' and b2.lname = 'Fox' and
                    b2.f_lname = b.f_lname and b2.f_fname = f.f_fname
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from births b2
              where b2.fname = 'Michael' and b2.lname = 'Fox' and
                    b2.m_lname = b.m_lname and b2.m_fname = b.m_fname);
```

Comment: Doesn't that still use nesting though? There is a select inside a select.